# Getting a bad disparity map despite a good stereo calibration

Tags: python, opencv, stereo-3d

I'm currently working on creating a disparity map using opencv and python. Both my individual camera calibration return an RMS error under 0.15 and my stereo calibrate returns an RMS error under 0.2, both of these seem good. The translation matrix that stereo calibrate returns gives a correct distance for how far away the cameras are and the other values are reasonable too. It seems like I should be getting a good disparity map, but most of the time it's seemingly random even after tuning the parameters of stereoBM. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSKbR.png) is the disparity map I get using [rectified left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEejk.jpg) and [rectified right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ymuV.jpg) images. This is using stereoBM but stereoSGBM isn't much better.

[Here](https://www.uctronics.com/arducam-12mp-2-synchronized-stereo-camera-bundle-kit-for-nvidia-jetson-nano-and-xavier-nx-two-12-3mp-imx477-camera-modules-with-cs-lens-and-camarray-stereo-camera-hat.html) are the cameras I'm using and they're hardware synchronized. Most of my code is copied from [this](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d9/db7/tutorial_py_table_of_contents_calib3d.html) openCV tutorial and my stereoCalibrate was taken from [this](https://learnopencv.com/making-a-low-cost-stereo-camera-using-opencv/) article. I'm using a printed chessboard with squares that are 20mmx20mm on 11x9 paper and I'm making sure to take photos at multiple angles and that cover the entire fov. I'm downsizing my images to 960x540 from 1920x1080. My code is a bit long but I can post it if necessary.

I've also drawn epilines on the images and it turns out like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLfrP.png) and feature mapping looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNBQF.png). Both have some weird anomalies of not being fully accurate. Is this an issue with my calibration or are these images difficult for these algorithms to process?

This has frustrated me as it seems like I'm doing everything right and my code should be all good but I'm still not getting good results. Am I falling into some sort of common mistake? I looked into my camera documentation and I don't believe they're automatically adjusting anything that would affect a calibration. Any help is greatly appreciated as this has been causing me issues for awhile.

Comment: Can you try with lossless compression instead of using jpg? How do you capture? Gstreamer and VideoCapture might have internal buffers so that you maybe dont grab the same timestamped images, even if both cameras are triggered synchronously.

Comment: @Micka Using png gave about the same result. This is my gstreamer pipeline that I'm using `nvarguscamerasrc sensor-id=0 ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=(int)4056, height=3040,format=(string)NV12, framerate=(fraction)13/1 ! nvvidconv flip-method=0 ! video/x-raw, format=(string)BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR ! appsink drop=1`. This is on a nvidia jetson nx so it's a little unique. After I set up the pipeline with opencv's VideoCapture, I use the .read() function in its own thread to get frames, and each frame is two images h stacked, one from each camera

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this post from LearnOpenCV (https://learnopencv.com/depth-perception-using-stereo-camera-python-c/) contains the answer on your question in the chapter about Block Matching For Dense Stereo Correspondence. If the quality of your Stereo Calibration and Rectification is Ok, maybe you need to adjust some parameters responsible for disparity map quality

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).